# View source function independent of user rating, so that can learn from others

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Dear All

Many users wish that questions and answers are typeset in
LaTeX. There is some hurdle for users that don't use LaTeX
very often.

Now I observed my self to use the edit function on my old
posts, so as to copy paste some LaTeX to new questions or
answers.

Unfortunately I was not able to use the edit function on
posts not owned by me. But some source viewing functionality
would be very useful, so as to learn LaTeX type setting
from others.

The problem is especially annoying when somebody posts
a perfect LaTeX answer to the own question, and the source
of this answer cannot be viewed.

Best Regards

P.S.: Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The source for that post I made at MO is here, too: https://gist.github.com/997771

Comment: I don't understand the question. Even if you are not logged on, you will find an "edit" link next to each post.

Comment: @Jan: I said "even if you are not logged on".

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask questions related to MO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on any piece of LaTeX. The menu popping up gives you lots of options, but "Show Source" is what you want here.